# turn image through 90 degrees and position absolutely within div

Tags: css

Ok here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/mnmc7/

Code is very very basic at this stage, but essentially here is the css:

```
.Box {
    width:660px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    height:140px;
}
#Logo {
    position:absolute;
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
    z-index:inherit;
    zoom:1;
}
```

here is the html so far:

```
<div class="Box">
                                <div id="Logo">
                                    <img src="http://images.domain.com.au/img/Agencys/16067/logo_16067.GIF" width="130px">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The idea is to get the image to exactly sit inside the div, and float it to the left with say 5px margin. So that it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why go through all the trouble and rotate the actual image to begin with?

Comment: did you vote this down ?

Comment: Have you seen this [jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/)?  Might be useful in this case.  Edit:  wrong link, I actually meant this one:  http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tybro0103/mnmc7/25/

Comment: @tybro0103 perfect... I was getting my A's and R's in a knot . Thanks

Comment: @422 - nope - I see no up or down votes at all on your question. Still think it is a waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to the logo:

```
position:relative;
float:left;
top:43px;
left:-33px;
```

Also in Internet Explorer 9 it appears they want you to use rotation=4

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/mnmc7/21/

Comment: It's important to explain why these numbers work. Especially if the image dimensions change, as noted by the OP.

Comment: Works great but still adopting positioning of main page... no idea why, my nesting is clean. As you can see from your fiddle

Comment: It's adopting the position of the main page because your parent element has a static position. Give it a position:relative if you want a nested element to have position:absolute relative to IT not the WINDOW :)

Answer (score 2):

Just give #logo a top and left value for it's position if you want to do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/mnmc7/13/

Comment: The issue I have is it positions itself absolutely to top of page, yet I have it nested correctly, so changing to relative

Comment: If you want to position relative to its parent element, just add position: relative to the parent. Absolute positioning will position with respect to the nearest positioned parent.

Comment: Now I am getting confused. The parent div ( as per example ) is positioned in page with no relative or absolute positioning. So the child div ( being the logo ) just isnt playing ball...

Comment: So in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnmc7/26/ I have the parent position set to relative and the logo position set to absolute. Is this not working for you?